# UTF-8 email encoding issue - can you see an error in this code?

Tags: php, email, function, utf-8, character-encoding

Can you spot any issues in the below code that means emails sent from our website are not being encoded as UTF-8 and are showing random characters replacing the correct characters? Email source example:

```
Nekdo pr�ve prispel na V� projekt.
```

The email form page is encoded as UTF-8 which sends the data to a separate sendresults.php page (also a UTF-8 encoded page) with the following code. Perhaps I'm missing encoding here to ensure the email is sent in UTF-8:

```
<?php
$subject = 'Contact from mywebsite.com';
$emailadd = 'info@mywebsite.com';
$url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/contactconfirmation.php';
$req = '1';

$text = "Results from form:\n\n";
$space = ' ';
$line = '
';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
if ($req == '1')
{
if ($value == '')
{echo "$key is empty";die;}
}
$j = strlen($key);
if ($j >= 20)
{echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";die;}
$j = 20 - $j;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++)
{$space .= ' ';}
$value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
$conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
$text .= $conc;
$space = ' ';
}
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$emailadd.'');
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

Comment: you may want to add a tag with the programming language you are using. Especially because you use built-in functions. Moreover, I would also include in the question the source of the mail message as it was delivered.

Comment: The problem is in `$body`, not in the code you show. Where does it come from?

Comment: Why not use phpmailer, and avoid those headaches? http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ You can specify the encoding of the mail, among a lot of others features.

Comment: @macjohn phpmailer is a great idea in general, but won't solve this specific problem: The data is wrongly encoded

Comment: This is the simple set-up I'm using with both pages encoded as UTF-8: http://www.dreamweaverclub.com/dreamweaver-php-form.php

Answer (score 3):

Your E-Mail code looks fine; the culprit is `$body`, which seems to contain ISO-8859-1 characters (or characters from some other encoding). You need to check your application to see where that happens.

If `$body` comes from a database, it could be the classical ["mySQL default connection charset is ISO-8859-1](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8/mysql)" problem (search for `defaults to a latin1 connection` in the link).

Comment: I've removed the `$body` line in the hope that it was confusing the rest of the code. No change as yet. The data does not come from the database - mail from our contact page for example doesn't encode properly despite the page and code being encoded as UTF-8. Something isn't working!

Comment: @JoeW not sure I understand. `$body` contains your text, doesn't it? Where does it come from?

Comment: I've edited my original post to hopefully shed more light on this.

Comment: @Joe that looks quite okay. Are you 1000% sure the E-Mail form is UTF-8 encoded? Is the browser's "charset" menu set to that encoding in the menu?

Comment: I have the form set as: `<form action="sendresults.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Contact form" target="_self">`

Comment: @JoeW is the actual *page* UTF-8 encoded? You shouldn't be needing  `accept-charset` if it is. (Nor should the enctype be necessary, you should be able to get rid of that either way)

Comment: Yes, the contactform.php and sendresults.php pages are both UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @Joe Is the browser's "charset" menu set to that encoding when you open it? You are 100% sure?

Comment: The website itself is in Czech and all characters show up correctly even on the contact form. It's becoming a mystery. Do you think altering the 'Unicode Normalization Form' from 'C' will have any effect

Comment: @JoeW do you have a live URL of the page?

Comment: I tried all the options with that, no change. Yes, click here: http://alturl.com/bnbme

Comment: @JoeW really strange, that's UTF-8 all right! Can you get rid of the `htmlspecialchars_decode()` just to make sure? It shouldn't change anything but I can't see anything else.

Comment: Yes I removed that line pretty early on. I can only think it's something to do with that section of code.

Comment: @Joe what happens if you output it there instead of E-Mailing it? (You'd need to show a UTF-8 header too, though)

Comment: How would I go about trying that?

Comment: @JoeW I'll show you in a minute, but just to make sure: `Nekdo pr�ve prispel na V� projekt` is something you enter into the form, yes? It's not hardcoded in the PHP file?

Comment: Yes, that is form data entered by the user. However, some other automated emails that occur when a user signs up (among other things) use the same commands from the top of my original post and show up incorrectly also... so I really don't think it's a fault on our contact form's encoding.

Comment: @Joe you can output the data using `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); echo $_POST["Message"];` instead of the code to build and send the mail. If it shows up broken there as well, it's to do with the form; if it's okay there, it's in the mail code. I'm off to bed now, I hope you figure it out, good luck! Otherwise, leave a note here, maybe I have an idea tomorrow.

Comment: It showed up just fine 'n dandy. Grrr! So, it's something to do with the mail code.

Comment: @JoeW what if you E-Mail the `$_POST["Message"]` directly, without processing it in those loops? That might help locate the problem. (Although I can't see any in the code you show.)

Comment: So after many more hours of investigation, our contact form just uses the code as shown in the edited question above. Why would the UTF-8 characters not be sending correctly - any ideas?